# How to make this Shape by css

Tags: css, css-shapes

how to make this shape by css and wirte the code
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjlrC.jpg]

This code for Translate this Shape

```
#base { 
    background: red; 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 55px; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100px; 
} 

#base:before { 
    border-bottom: 35px solid red; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    content: ""; 
    height: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -35px; 
    width: 0; 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't ask us to write the code for you

Answer (score 4):

Please see below. You can fiddle with the height of the triangle by changing the value of -70/70 pixels.

```css
.base {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: red;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
.base::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -70px;
 left: 0;
 border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
 border-width: 0 100px 70px 100px;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
```

Comment: Can you do it in reverse؟

Comment: @EzzaldinMamdouh within`.base { }` drop `margin-top: 100px;`, In `.base::before { }` make the following changes: `top: 100px;`, `border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;`, `border-width: 70px 100px 0 100px;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
#base{ width: 0; height: 0;border-left: 85px solid transparent;border-right: 90px solid transparent;border-bottom: 100px solid red;margin:0;}
#rect{ width: 175px;height: 100px; background: red; margin:0;}
```